# How to test an Ionic toast message with protractor (selenium)

Tags: javascript, selenium, ionic-framework, protractor, e2e-testing

After writing some text into an alert window a toast message will be displayed in the app.
I want to test whether the text the toast message displays is the right one.

The problem is that inside the DOM the text is inside a shadow root and it will only be displayed for 2 seconds.
How can I reach inside the shadow root with protractor?

this for example:
`element(by.deepCss(".toast-message")).getText();`

throws this:
`Failed: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified`

```
<ion-toast class="md hydrated" id="ion-overlay-40" tabindex="-1" style="z-index: 60040;">
 #shadow-root(open) 
   <div class="toast-wrapper toast-bottom" style="bottom: calc(8px + var(--ion-safe-area-bottom, 0px));"> 
    <div class="toast-container" part="container">
     <div class="toast-content">
      <div class="toast-message" part="message"> "Text that I want to check is written here!" </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</ion-toast>
```

Edit:
I managed to solve it with this method

```
static getToastMessage(expectedMessage: string): void {
        browser.executeScript("return document.querySelector('ion-toast').shadowRoot.querySelector('.toast-message')").then(
            (toastMessage: WebElement) =>{
                expect(toastMessage.getText()).toEqual(expectedMessage);
            }
        )
    }
```

Comment: Did you tried with the expected condition

Comment: I also tried: 
querySelector and EC 
Maybe I just did it the wrong way do you have an idea?

Comment: What did you write with EC, the code, could you provide it?

Comment: As I suspected I had a mistake in my code when trying to use querySelector 
Thank you :)

Comment: @Camillo what do you mean by "Ionic"? Is this the website of the application you are referencing? https://ionic.com/